# Detecting the delete key being pressed

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have looked around for ways to detect when the delete key is pressed.  I came across Apple's key handling documentation and also some people trying this with work arounds.  I am not sure which method to pursue.  What I want to do is very simple:

```
-(void)deleteKeyWasPressed {

if (myTextField.text.length == 0) {

[previousTextField becomeFirstResponder]; 

}

}
```

But as far as I know this method does not exist.

What would be the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

iOS has no direct support for detecting the delete key (or any key other than Return). The best you can do is implement the `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` delegate method. When the user taps the Delete key, the replacement string will be the empty string.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    if (string.length == 0) {
        // handle Delete (but this also handles the Cut menu as well)
    } else {
        // some other key or text is being pasted.
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, but doesn't work when you paste, cut or delete. The method is called, but for some reason the content size it's not updated. I think this method is called before change the text in the text view, or before changing the text content

Comment: Yes, this is called when the user does cut, delete, or paste. And yes, it is called before the change is actually made. That's the point. The `string` parameter will reflect which. If the user does a cut or delete, the `string` will be the empty string and the range will be the range being cut or deleted. If the user is pasting, the `string` will be the new text and the range will be the range being replaced.

Comment: Thank you @rmaddy. I finally solve my issue by calling `performSelector: afterDelay:` and i do what i need 0.1 sec after `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` is called. It's not a good way to do that but it´s work for me by the moment.

Answer (score 1):

The way that I have implemented it is to save the previous length of the textfield somewhere, and then compare the previous length to the current length. If the previous length is greater than the current length, then the delete key was pressed. Works well for me.

Comment: This idea doesn't handle the case when a user selects some text and then pastes text from the clipboard and the pasted text is shorter than the selected text.

Comment: Good point. That is not a risk in my implementation, but would probably be one for his.